# How to provide multiple test categories in vstest task in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, vstest, vstest.console.exe, azure-pipelines-tasks

My project has some Nunit tests with certain tags called categories.

For example: 32 bit app tests have `x32` as tag and 64 bit app tests have `x64` as tag.

Now using vstest task i am able to run tests for one category like this:

```
TestCategory=x32
```

when I want to run multiple categories in same task I gave `TestCategory=x32,x64` and it didn't work. The task failed without any errors in the console.

I even tried

```
TestCategory=x32|x64: in this case only x64 tests are ran.  
TestCategory=x32,x64: test task failed without any errors
```

Any idea on how to provide multiple categories ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to provide multiple test categories in vstest task in azure pipelines

According to the document [/category option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms182489(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#category):

- **/category:"group1|group2" runs tests that are in test category
  "group1" or "group2". Tests that are in both test categories will
  also be run.**

To use this with VS Test task, we could specify it like following:

```
TestCategory=x32|TestCategory=x64
```

**Update:**

> but, i need to run all the tests which are present in both categories.
> is this possible?

If you want to run all the tests which are present in both categories, you could try to use following in the vstest task:

```
TestCategory=x32&TestCategory=x64
```

Comment: I guess this option will run either of 2 test categories and tests that are present in both categories (intersection fof 2 categories). but, i need to run all the tests which are present in both categories. is this possible?

Comment: there is a bit of confusion in the wording i guess. what I am trying to achieve is. for example x32 category of tests have T1, T2 tests and x64 has T3,T4 tests. Now I need to run T1,T2,T3,T4 all of them.

Comment: @saikartheekchalla, um, Isn't this your initial question? You just use the `TestCategory=x32|TestCategory=x64`, it will execute all the tests under the x32 category and x64.